# AWS s3 add User-Defined Metadata without storing `x-amz-meta-`

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Im using AWS s3 to store files, i need to add User-Defined Metadata

`"Content-Disposition": attachment;filename=filename.txt` when uploading the file/object to aws so i would be able to download it, when uploading with javascript i need to add `x-amz-meta-content-disposition`, now in s3 the metadate Key is stored as `x-amz-meta-content-disposition` but the file is not downloding, when i remove manually in AWS console the first part `x-amz-meta-` and only leave `content-disposition` then im able to download.

Now my question is: how can i upload the file using javascript and `x-amz-meta-` should be removed and just be
`"Content-Disposition": attachment;filename=filename.txt`

Answer (score 2):

This has been reported as a bug few times:

- https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/1353
- https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-aws-plugin/issues/166
- https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-aws-plugin/issues/40

Thus I think you are experiencing same.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you guys want to add metadata Content-Disposition: attachmemt? then simply try run cp command or sync command with this argument...

**aws s3 sync s3://bucketname/ s3://newbucketname/ --content-disposition "attachment"**

this will work